# Can a top-level class or interface have the "static" modifier?

Tags: java, class, static

Can a top-level class or interface be declared as static?

Example:

```
// File A.java
static Class A
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: what effect are you trying to achieve by declaring it static?

Comment: What would you expect that to mean?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 5):

No. `static` only applies to nested classes and tells that instances of the nested class do not need an instance of the surrounding class to be instantiated. As such, it makes no sense as applied to top classes.

Comment: Tecnically, an inner class is a nested class that is _not_ declared static. (See [Java Language Specification §8.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.3).) So static does not apply to inner classes by definition. Nevertheless, the sense of this answer is correct.

Comment: But a lot doesn't make sense [in Java]. I honestly wouldn't have been surprised to find out it was just ignored :)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, top-level classes cannot be declared static; see [JLS Section 8.1.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.1).

> Not all modifiers are applicable to all kinds of class declarations ... **The access modifier static pertains only to member classes** ...

Answer (score 0):

All top level classes by default are static.

For those too hooked up about definition of statics and compiler errors.

A class itself is an object with application scope. So it's implicitly static.

Comment: I read somewhere that only inner classes can be static. But your statement contradicts the same.

Comment: More correctly, modifier static makes no sense -- only inner classes have the distinction, wrt whether they get "hidden" reference back to instance of enclosing class. Hence, it is meaningless and not supported.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by static.  If you say it means "independent of an instance," then, yes, technically, all top-level classes are static.   Only inner classes can be *declared* static, though, because that's where the only ambiguity is.

Comment: The compiler will complain if you _declare_ a top-level class `static`.

Comment: @ted i never said it wouldn't. :)

Comment: @lc2817 so what does static mean then?

Comment: @SidMalani it means that the class can't be instantiated (for any class except the main). It is a sort of convention that the entry class of the program (the top level class) is not static as stated in the documentation. Did you try to compile a program with that?

Comment: @lc2817 look at the comment. I never claimed it will compile. But the point is understanding of the definition that matters.

Comment: @SidMalani but if it is by default static, it means that you could make it static with no trouble and it is not the case, so it is wrong.

Comment: @SidMalani - OP was specifically asking about declaring a top-level class to be static. Saying a top-level class is by default static makes no sense. The entire concept of "static" only applies to members of a class. By definition, a top-level class is not a member of a class.

Comment: @lc2817 `static` doesn't 'mean the class can't be instantiated (for any class except the main)'; and 'if it is by default static, it means that you could make it static' is a *non sequitur.*

Answer (score 0):

In java a top level class can't be defined as static.

read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html)

Answer (score 0):

basically, you can make a static inner class but not top level class(outer one)
I think this post get a better explanation.
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html
hopefully, it helps